# Python Tesseract Error in Mac: Unsupported Image Obect

Tags: python-3.x, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am using a Mac and installed tesseract successfully.

However, when am writing the code to read a jpeg or png file it gives me an error:
TypeError: Unsupported image object

The code snippet is as follows:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
img = cv2.imread('image.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you `print(img)` to verify image is being read properly? `pytesseract.image_to_string()` expects an Image object, which is returned by `Image.open()` but I am not sure whether `cv2.imread()` returns an image array or object. If you are allowed to use `PIL` I have experienced no problems until now.

Comment: changed code to PIL and opened the image. I am getting this output <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=1068x1600 at 0x7FEDA3DD5DC0>.  When using pytesseract.image_to_string after this, I am getting the following error: TesseractNotFoundError: tesseract is not installed or it's not in your PATH.

Comment: Ok so it correctly loaded the image, now you have to make sure tesseract executable ins your path. What operating system are you on?

Comment: am on mac.. figured it out. The addition of line "pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/bin/tesseract'" fixed it :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the statement:

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = '/usr/local/Cellar/tesseract/4.1.1/bin/tesseract'
```

to your code before using pytesseract. To know where pytesseract is installed in your mac you can use the command as shown below if tesseract is installed using brew.

```
brew list tesseract
```